# Notations for statistical / systematic / numeric errors?

Tags: notation, statistics, error-analysis, conventions

I constantly see the notation 
$$
5.143(13)
$$
for specifying that a value was measures / calculated to be 5.143 with an estimated error of 0.013. I have come to wonder though, just how commonly accepted the notation and variants are. After all, if it is commonly accepted, why have I found some literature explicitly stating what it means (though it might just have been distinguishing systematic and statistical errors).

Additionally I'm not sure it would still work for something like

$$
513(30) \equiv 513 \pm 30
$$
or 
$$
51.3(30) \equiv 51.3 \pm  3.0
$$

Is this notation a commonly accepted convention, that can be reasonably expected still to be understood by people reading a paper written now in 50 years? Is it understood in cases like those above?

Answer (score 1):

In the field I used to work in the notation using ± is quite common. However, the number after the ± is then usually not the standard error but indicates the confidence interval. This is usually 2 times the standard error, but it can also be a factor 3. In you last example this would be 51.3±6.0 using a 'coverage factor' of 2.

Instead of the notation you use where you express the standard error in the last digits you could also use 51.3(3.0) (last example) or 5.124(0.013) (first example). So, you add the digit explicitly.

I would recommend explaining exactly what is meant the first time the notation is used. Also because you might want to explain what exactly is included in the standard error and how it's calculated.

The document [Guidelines for evaluating and expressing the uncertainty of NIST measurement results](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/guidelines/TN1297/tn1297s.pdf) and especially [Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf) are considered to be standard documents. They discuss both notations.