# Nuclear decay information

Tags: radiation

I'm looking at some gamma spectroscopy calibration data, produced by a known source (semi known... the source was last calibrated 2006...)

My question is, looking at for example http://www.nucleide.org/DDEP_WG/Nuclides/Co-57_tables.pdf or http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=270057

In the table for the gamma from Co-57, the KeV and #photons values have a number in a bracket beside their main number. **What is the meaning of those numbers?**

My guess is it's to make sure we only have whole numbers of photons (As required).

Comment: Just a small nitpick: brackets = [,] while parenthesis = (,). On topic, you might want to see this [related post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79325/notations-for-statistical-systematic-numeric-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the numbers in brackets are error bars. For example, 706,42(2) means $706.42\pm .02$.